# Copying data from word table cell throws type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

Thanks for looking into this.

I am trying to get values from word table into variable. For most part it works but for the last part I could not. Error is in this below line after search text is like "*Interest Payment Dates (t)*"
`retVal = pTable.Cell(oRow.Index+1, 5)`
my guess is that because it looks like there is a table inside the bigger table. Any suggestion regarding how do I get dates highlighted in yellow into my retVal array? Pls see image

```
Public Function GetCellValue(ByRef pTable As Word.Table, ByVal pRow As Long, ByVal otext As String) As Variant
On Error GoTo Err_GetCellValue

Dim procName As String
Dim retVal As Variant
Dim strValue As String
Dim oRow As Variant
Dim oCell As Variant
Dim found As Boolean
Dim DQ As Variant

procName = "basGeneral::GetCellValue()"
found = False

For Each oRow In pTable.Rows

For Each oCell In oRow.Cells



    If oCell.Range.Text Like otext Then
        
        
        If otext Like "*Interest Payment Dates (t)*" Then
            retVal = pTable.Cell(oRow.Index+1, 5)
                    
        Else
            retVal = pTable.Cell(oRow.Index, 3)
        
        End If

        retVal = WorksheetFunction.Clean(retVal)
        DQ = Chr(34)
        
            If IsNumeric(retVal) Then
                retVal = Replace(retVal, DQ, "")
            End If
        
         found = True
         Exit For
    End If

Next oCell

If found = True Then Exit For

Next oRow
```

[Word file to copy specific data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txnxf.png)

Comment: Try declare `retVal` as `String` - `Dim retVal As String` and `pTable.Cell(oRow.Index+1, 5)` should most probably be `pTable.Cell(oRow.Index+1, 5).Range.Text`

Comment: @RaymondWu Thanks raymond. But this does not work. 
I guess it is because there is a table inside table in that word document.
There are dozens of such word files to copy data from.

Comment: To refer to yth table in xth table in thisdocument --- `thisdocument.Tables(x).Tables(y)` .. Thisdocument.Tables.Count may give you only 1 but not tables count inside that table. .. Like this.. `Thisdocument.Tables(1).Tables(2).Cell(2,3).range.Text`

Comment: Thanks everyone. Suggestion from @Naresh solved my problem.

Comment: @ShriIyer .. You can post your own answer and accept it.. It will be good for reference later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me -

To refer to yth table in xth table in thisdocument ---
`thisdocument.Tables(x).Tables(y)`

`Thisdocument.Tables.Count` may give you only 1 but not tables count inside that table.
Like this - `Thisdocument.Tables(1).Tables(2).Cell(2,3).range.Text`